# iOS - Purchasing subscription with in-app purchasing

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm using subscriptions for in-app purchase.
I am testing the application.
I'm creating the objects for SKProduct etc and initiating the purchase process.
Its showing the alert to purchase also.
But meanwhile the following delegate is being called:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{   
    NSLog(@"Transaction Count: %d",[transactions count]);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"Purchased");
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed");
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored");
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know when transaction is initiated and depending on the transaction status, this delegate will be called, but I am confused why this is being called during initial stage itself? And due to this my app is crashing some times.

Comment: Have you called `finishTransaction:` on `SKPaymentQueue` after processing the `SKPaymentTransaction`? If not then StoreKit will keep telling you about purchases you've previously made each time you run the app.

Comment: Yes, i'm calling "finishTransaction"

Comment: What is the state during the initial stage?

Comment: For the first time, it won't be called. Once purchased, from next time onwards during validating, it gives "SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased"

Comment: Ah right well then yes, that's because it's already been purchased so it goes straight to purchased state. What's the problem with that?